# Codenameone: WebBrowser pull to refresh issue

Tags: codenameone

As title said I have a issue to use “pull to refresh” feature with WebBrowser in Codenameone.
The issue is that “pull to refresh” feature cannot be used with BorderLayout and I need this type of layout to expand WebBrowser over entire screen.

I’ve tried different mix of layouts combinations to avoid usage of BorderLayout so that “pull to refresh” can work but the final result is that I cannot expand WebBrowser over entire screen and have at same time the “pull to refresh” working.

Question: How can I have WebBrowser expanded over entire screen so that I can use “pull to refresh” feature for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowser` is a [Peer Component](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/05/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html) hence it handles everything natively including pointer events. This means our pull to refresh logic can't possibly work within a web browser and you have quite a few other limitations.

If you want pull to refresh functionality in a `WebBrowser` you will need to do it using JavaScript, its an all or nothing issue. FYI You should use a `BorderLayout` with `WebBrowser`.